# Android subscription purchase returns same order IDs

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

According to Google's documentation order IDs of subscriptions have the following format:

> 12999556515565155651.5565135565155651 (base order number)  12999556515565155651.5565135565155651..0 (initial purchase orderID)  12999556515565155651.5565135565155651..1 (first recurrence orderID)  12999556515565155651.5565135565155651..2 (second recurrence orderID)

And I understood that changed order ID (added ..X) was return from Google IAP service when users subscription period is extended.

But Google IAP  always returns the same order ID: "12999556515565155651.5565135565155651"

Is that right? Do I need to make another check step to check if users subscriptions are extended?